# ios - how to keep app running in background only if the location manager is runnig

Tags: ios, background, cllocationmanager

I'm using location background mode, but that makes the app runs forever. what I wanna do is when the location manager is active (user pressed start saving my location) and the app enter the back ground mode the app must stay running (achieved). But, if the user didn't pressed the button to start saving the location or he pressed the button "stop saving my locations" then the app can be killed or suspended when it is in the background. 
Now the app is running on the background even if it has no work to do. and it drains battery.

Comment: Simply tell your `CLLocationManager` instance to `stopUpdatingLocation`

Comment: I do, but the app keeps running, "stops saving my locations" button calls stopUpdatingLocation, and also when reaching a destination the stopUpdatingLocation is called. but the app keeps running

Comment: What do you mean "the app keeps running"?  It is still delivering calls to your location delegate methods?

Comment: No, the stopUpdatingLocation stops the location manager from reporting location, But the app keeps alive, it does not get killed or suspended by the ios it consume battery and when I click on the app icon it resume from where I left and it does not get launched again from the begining so it was running doing nothing

Comment: iOS will keep your app in memory until another app requires that memory.  It is suspended and it isn't consuming battery or CPU unless you are actively performing work.  Also apps running under the debugger in Xcode are treated differently to apps that are launched normally.

Comment: I don't think so, what apple stated is that if an app is sent to the background it keeps running for like 10 minutes (now it becomes 3). after that it get suspended. when you add a background mode, the app will run forever. what you have describe is how android works not ios.

Comment: No,  you can request to perform a long-running task in the background for up to 3 minutes.  Your app will be kept suspended indefinitely if no other app requires the memory and the user doesn't "kill" your app from the switcher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73462/discussion-between-firas-kadhum-and-paulw11).